# I created this React application to a fetch API that I created, but got the error message "TypeError: video.map is not a function". Below is the code:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud, fetch-api

import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const VideoPage = () => {

```
const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVideoData = async ()=> {
        const result = await Axios(`http://localhost:8080/api/video`);
        setVideo(result.data)
    }

    if(video){
        setLoading(false);
    }

    const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
        !video && fetchVideoData();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);

}, [video]);

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Video Info</h2>
        {loading ? <h3>Loading...</h3> : video.map(video => (
            <a key={video.id} href= {`video/${video.id}`}><p>{video.title}</p></a>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

}

export default VideoPage;

Why is it not being recognized?

Answer (score 0):

On first render before useEffect is finished. Video is null and you can't call .map on null. You should instead do

```
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
```

This would cause your videos to be an empty array on first render. Then once it's updated it correctly shows everything.